# Make Xcode compile only touched files even on product name change

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, incremental-build

I have a very big source code, say 2000 classes. I make different executables(.ipa) using the source code. The changes among the executables are some keys in the info.plist file and the product name.

Whenever I change the product name Xcode compiles all the source files(2000+) again. If I don't change the product name and change only the info.pilst file it compiles only the info.plist file which indicates that I do not have any weird things in the source code.

I don't want the files to be compiled again and again as it takes long time, an incremental compile with a different product name is really nice to have.

Is there anyway I can achieve it?. Or is there a key like `CFBundleName` that controls the name displayed under the app icon without making the Xcode compile again.( Changing only `CFBundleName` doesn't make the Xcode to recompile however it is not changing the bundle name unless the project is cleaned. UPDATE: Touching the info.plist make it work) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to change the name that is shown, use CFBundleDisplayName.